# Calculating the residue as part of Matsubara summation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, condensed-matter, fermions, greens-functions

On page no. $166$ of "Many-body quantum theory in
condensed matter physics" by Henrik Bruus & Karsten Flensberg, while explaining the summation of Matsubara frequency, the following calculation is made :
$ Res_{\substack{z=ik_n}}[n_F (z)]=lim_{\substack{z \rightarrow ik_n}} \frac{(z-ik_n)}{\exp {(\beta z)} +1}=lim \substack{\delta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta}{[\exp {(\beta ik_n)}\exp {(\beta \delta)}]+1}=-\frac{1}{\beta} $,
where $n_F (z)$ is the Fermi distribution function,  $n_F (z) = \frac{1}{\exp {(\beta z)}+1}$.    **Question :** What is $' \delta ' $ and the  accompanying (second-last) expression?

Comment: Do you mean what is $\delta$ physically? Mathematically, $\delta$ is just $z-ik_n$. 

You can see this by considering
$$
lim_{\substack{z \rightarrow ik_n}} \frac{(z-ik_n)}{\exp {\beta z} +1}\Bigg|_{z\rightarrow\delta + ik_n} = lim_{\substack{\delta\rightarrow 0}} \frac{\delta}{\exp {\beta (\delta+ik_n)} +1} = lim_{\substack{\delta\rightarrow 0}} \frac{\delta}{[\exp {\beta ik_n}\exp{\beta\delta}] +1}
$$

Comment: Could you please provide the very first expression? It seems that $\delta$ is needed to make the sum convergent. It is well-known fact. For instance, if one want to calculate free energy, it is quite easy to see divergent contribution from zero modes.

Comment: @Artem The previous content says the following : " In order
to be more general, we define the two generic sums (only Fermionic sum is shown here): " $ S^F (\tau)= \frac {1}{\beta} \sum_{\substack {ik_n}}g(ik_n)\exp {ik_n \tau}$, where, $ ik_n =$ fermion frequency. After this is stated what is given in my question.

Comment: @Akoben Yes, in the question I meant what is '$\delta$' mathematically. Do you have any physical interpretation for it as well? Also, could you please show how did we get $- \frac{1}{\beta}$ as the result? Thanks